# changing grub boot order

Tags: boot, dual-boot

so i am triple booting Win 7 (yeah i know) Ubuntu and BT5 on my Dell Latitude e4300.

it is on a single harddisc with a partition for each of the OS'

as usual it is the last installed to be the first on the list and booting into if no other choice is made in the time slot before boot. That means in my case that BT5 boots auto, and i need it like 4 or 5 times a month.

Now, i have tried with a grub editor for Ubuntu, i can re arrange the partitions, but when i save and restart, it is the same configuration as i am trying to alter.

in windows. well. windows "advanced" settings, only lets me see that i have several partitions, but only one OS. windows 7..

i would love if someone could help me with maybe even a GUI way to rearrange the boot order of my GNU GRUB ?

if no GUI, terminal will do ..

Comment: dos this mean that it is not possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this Grub Editor. Give it a go...

To install Grub-Customizer open Terminal (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and copy or type the following commands in the Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Then to run it

```
grub-customizer
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Just remember, after saving your grub menu, click on File>Install to MBR to make it stick