# Migration from XP to Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, windows-xp

I have an older Dell Inspiron. I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on it.

The originally OS is Win XP and right now both OS are running on the PC alongside each other, with XP as the default system.

What I would like to do is to have Ubuntu as the default OS and eventually get rid of XP.

I anyone out there can help, it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: So, in what way is XP default? Do you, perhaps, have a wubi (inside Windows) Ubuntu installation?

Comment: When I start up the PC I can manually select if I want to run XP or Ubuntu, but if I do nothing the machine automatically starts up XP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [changing grub boot order](http://askubuntu.com/q/276249/36315)

Comment: Making Ubuntu boot by default is feasible, but first we need to know how it is installed - wubi or dual boot. Let us see the output of `sudo fdisk -l` from Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

The boot order and default is determined by GRUB, the boot loader. The default entry is determined by the `GRUB_DEFAULT=` setting in `/etc/default/grub`; the first "menuentry" has a value of "0". So, if Ubuntu is the second entry, just edit this file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

and change it to:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=1
```

You can also change the GRUB_TIMEOUT to a lower value if you don't like to wait too long